# How to use Python classes exported by Selenium IDE?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I need help on how to instantiate a class exported by Selenium IDE

I'm newbie either to Python (3.7.3) and Selenium IDE (3.12.0). I know how to use classes and objects but I've a problem with classes generated by Selenium IDE. Here is what I get

```
import pytest
import time
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class Test_SearchTrue():
  def setup_method(self, method):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    self.vars = {}

  def teardown_method(self, method):
    self.driver.quit()

  def test_testSearchTrue(self):
    ...

myTest = Test_SearchTrue()
myTest.setup_method(???)
```

My question is: what is the `method` argument in `setup_method()` and `teardown_method`?.